# MySQL SELECT 3 random and one static row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of answers for multiple choice questions. So you have three columns

ID Correct and Answer. ID is an auto increment Correct is a 0 or 1. 0 denotes incorrect answers as 1 denotes the reverse (A correct answer).

I need to select 4 rows in a random order (Or just be able to call upon them in a random order) 3 must be incorrect and the 4th must be correct.

Is this possible in a single query?

Comment: have you looked into using RAND()? --- also put up some data and anything you have tried.. makes it easier to get an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have reasonably small amount of rows in `answers` table then you can do something like this

```sql
SELECT id, question_id, correct, answer
  FROM answers
 WHERE question_id = 1 
   AND correct = 1
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT id, question_id, correct, answer
    FROM answers
   WHERE question_id = 1 
     AND correct = 0
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 3
)
 ORDER BY RAND()
```

**Note:** *that `RAND()` in `ORDER BY`is a very costly operation*

Sample output:

```
| ID | QUESTION_ID | CORRECT |   ANSWER |
|----|-------------|---------|----------|
|  7 |           1 |       0 |  answer7 |
| 10 |           1 |       0 | answer10 |
|  5 |           1 |       1 |  answer5 |
|  4 |           1 |       0 |  answer4 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ba67/4)** demo

Comment: Just want to reinforce that `ORDER BY RAND()` is a very bad idea. You're basically throwing away the use of any index for sorting, forcing mysql to create a temp table, and then doing a `filesort` on that temp table. It doesn't matter how small you set your `LIMIT` clause, ***all rows*** *must be randomized and sorted first*. MySQL cannot, and will not, do random anything efficiently. You would be much better off doing randomization in PHP rather than MySQL.